# How to debug why source code labeling fails in VSTS build?

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

We have many git repositories in VSTS and we would like to use source labeling function to be able to get more information. According to the setup at every successful build we should have a label in our source code. But it fails, VSO build says that it cannot tag the source code. In the log I cannot find anything usable. Do you know how to debug it? Do you have any information which helps get closer to the root cause?

[image: error]

Setup:

[image]

The strange things it that, in my personal repository it works fine and there are no significant difference between the two repository. Moreover, we have another build in the same repository with the same setup and it works fine.

**Update**:

- I checked the tags on the particular branch. Git tag says that there are no tags on this branch.

Comment: Try to change system.debug variable value to true and check whether there is detail errors.

Comment: Do you have black space in the tag name?

Comment: Space was the issue. The buildNumber is a string which contained a space and it is not preferred by VSTS/Git. Once we made the necessary changes the labeling works fine. @Eddie-MSFT, please write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SayusiAndo Glad to hear that. I have added a answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by the blank space in the tag name you want to create since VSTS does not accepted a tag name with blank space for now. Remove the blank space in your tag name should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below ways to debug this failure:

1. Check if the **tag named** `BuildID.14` has already existed in this repo: clone this repo locally -> use `git tag` command to check the tag name `BuildID.14` exist or not.

Or the way to debug locally: clone this repo (make sure it's latest) -> VS -> Branches -> select a branch -> view history -> right click a commit -> create tag -> enter tag name with `BuildID.14` to check if you can create or not.

2. Check **Build number format** in your build definition. Check if you are using the format like `BuildID$(Rev:.r)` or something, and you can change the format with unique one such as `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The tag doesn't exist. Unfortunately, I cannot change the build number format because we release from this branch. I updated my question.

Comment: Based on your update, did you only check a certain branch? You need to check all branches, because if other branches has the tag, this will also caused this failure. You can use `git tag`, it will show tags from all branches.

Comment: Nope, there are no tags in the branches. But, are you saying that if I have `Build.14` in branch `A` then VSTS cannot put `Build.14 tag` to branch `B`? Or it is a limitation in git itself?

Comment: No, I meant if you have tag `Build.14` in branchA, now you want to build branchB with **label sources**, your branchB will fail with **label sources** when the `$(build.buildNumber)`=`Build.14`.

Comment: Or another way to debug locally: clone this repo (make sure it's latest) -> VS -> Branches -> select a branch -> view history -> right click a commit -> create tag -> enter tag name with `BuildID.14` to check if you can create or not.